# The type or namespace name 'Ping' could not be found, although there is a dependencie and a using

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, console-application, ping

I am  creating a little program to ping a computer within a network.
For this i am trying to use the class ping, from

```
namespace System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
```

I am using ASP.NET 5.0 so i hava project.json file with my dependecies

```
  {
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {
        "NetworkSniffer": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0.0-beta2"
    },
    "commands": {
        "run": "run"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "aspnet50": {
            "dependencies": {
                "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-22231",
                "System.Net.NetworkInformation": "4.0.10-beta-22231"
            }
        },
        "aspnetcore50": {
            "dependencies": {
                "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-22231",
                "System.Net.NetworkInformation": "4.0.10-beta-22231"


            }
        }
    }
}
```

A simplefied version of the console code witch still gives the error is:

```
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
namespace TestApp
{
    public class Program
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Ping p = new Ping();   
        }

    }
}
```

the complete error when trying to compile this code is:

> Code:Error CS0246 Description:The type or namespace name 'Ping' could
>   not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?) Project:TestApp.ASP.NET Core 5.0 file:Program.cs line:9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Ping is not in the `System.Net.NetworkInfomation` package (does that package even exist?) for CoreCLR (`aspnetcore50`).

According to the [package search website](http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/), you need to add a reference to the `System.Net.Utilities` package.