# .Net Core add reference to System.Net.NetworkInformation

Tags: c#, .net, json, .net-core

How can I add reference to `System.Net.NetworkInformation` (for [Ping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx) class) in .NET Core without using Visual Studio? My `project.lock.json` is default I did not change anything in it. After adding

```
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
```

To my `Program.cs` I get error [CS0246](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/w7xf6dxs.aspx) after `dotnet run`:

```
(...)The type or namespace 'Ping' could not be found(...)
```

Every solution that I found is to add by VS but I'm using only VS Code and CMD Commands, as far as i see there is no way to add it by some [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/), and changing manualy `project.lock.json` file may be not the easiest solution, so how can i do it?

Comment: possible doublicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28449391/the-type-or-namespace-name-ping-could-not-be-found-although-there-is-a-depend)

Comment: You would manually change project.json, not project.lock.json according to the duplicate, then run `dotnet restore`