# .Net Core Ping Class - System.Net.Ping or System.Net.Utilities

Tags: asp.net-core, ping

I am trying to develop a feature to ping a PC on the network in .Net Core app.

According to this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28449391/the-type-or-namespace-name-ping-could-not-be-found-although-there-is-a-depend), it says I need to use System.Net.Utilities [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Utilities/).

My project.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.2.306",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Dapper": "1.50.2",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session": "1.1.0",
    "AutoMapper": "5.2.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.1",
    "System.Net.Utilities": "4.0.0-beta-23516"  
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.2.306",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win81"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

It added the library, I could build without any error.  But at runtime, I keep getting this error:

```
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Utilities, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Unknown location
ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
```

However, if I use System.Net.Ping [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Ping/), the same code works without any error and I could ping the host.

According to VS2015 Intellisense, it is suggesting to add System.Net.Utilities package which doesn't work.

I am confused and I couldn't figure out why I am getting that error when I use System.Net.Utilities.  Normally, if it is not compatible with .Net Core, we got the reference error / failed compilation straightaway.  But this time, it's completely different and I couldn't browse any page at all.

If in case, here is my code for Ping...

```
public async Task<double> PingPC(string host, int echoNum)
        {            
            long totalTime = 0;
            int timeout = 120;
            Ping pingSender = new Ping();

            for (int i = 0; i < echoNum; i++)
            {
                var reply = await pingSender.SendPingAsync(host, timeout);
                if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    totalTime += reply.RoundtripTime;
                }
            }
            return totalTime / echoNum;
        }
```

Could you please suggest what I am doing wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To get this version of System.Net.Utilities working with VS 2015, you must add dnxcore50 in the import section :

```
"netcoreapp1.1": {
  "imports": [
    "dnxcore50",
    "dotnet5.6",
    "portable-net45+win81"
  ]
}
```

If you decide to go with VS 2017, according to this article: http://www.natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/01/19/project-json-to-csproj/#imports, you must edit your csproj and add this line in PropertyGroup:

```
<PackageTargetFallback>dnxcore50</PackageTargetFallback>
```

You have a working example with VS2017 here : https://github.com/trenoncourt/ping-netcore